# Trouble with a "less than" function using for in loop. (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a for in loop that loops over the object and changes any value that is great than 10 to 0.

```
    var obj = {
      one:  1,
      two:  25,
      three:  3,
      four:  10,
      five:  15,
      six:  55,
    }

function greaterThan10(list)
{
  for (var prop in list){
    if (list[prop] > 10){
      list[prop] = 0;
      console.log(list)
      return list;
     }
}
}
greaterThan10(obj)
```

Console Output:

{ one: 1, two: 0, three: 3, four: 10, five: 15, six: 55 }

Comment: My mistake, that was something I as testing to see if I could effect the outcome before the > 10 ran. I have since deleted it with no improved effects.

Comment: Thankyou Ted for your help. "The greaterThan10 function will test the first property and either set it to 0 (if it was greater than 10) and return the list or will return the first property value (if it was no greater than 10). It no longer generates the console output that you report." assisted me in pinning down that that I had improperly placed my return and console.log commands within my loops. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You are returning from your function when you encounter the first property with value greater than 10. That's too soon, since you want to process all properties before returning. Just move the `return list` statement to after the `for` loop.

```
function greaterThan10(list)
{
  for (var prop in list){
    if (list[prop] > 10){
      list[prop] = 0;
     }
  }
  console.log(list)
  return list;
}
```

Also, to guard against more complex objects being passed as arguments, you might want to check against that. Just put this line:

```
if (!list.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
```

inside the `for` loop just before the `if` statement.

Comment: For few seconds you write the same answer before than me, lol. Upvote

Comment: @MrMins - Thanks. Speedy fingers pays off for once! (Instead of just embarrassing me.) :)